# Having trouble mapping json into React render

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

UPDATE: I am trying to:

1) Have a DataSourcesCard generate for each object.

2) Map out the key value pairs in the  component as a simple list.  (I am getting an error because "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {datasourceType, sqlDatabaseType, user, password, host, port, command, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.".

Fyi, fetch contains an array of 3 objects.  Each object contains id with a single key value pair plus a json object containing multiple pairs.

[This is the log of JSON after fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi8Gc.png)

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DataSourcesWrapper, 
AddDataSourcesButton, 
DataSourcesCard, 
CardContainer,
EditButton,
DeleteButton,
TextHeader,
UList,
Logo,
List,
Span } from './DataSources.style';
import { IconWindowCogs } from '../../../assets/images/icons/IconWindowCogs.svg';

export default class DataSources extends Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let $fp = navigator.platform + " " + navigator.appName + " " + navigator.language + " " + window.screen.width + " " + window.screen.height;
    fetch("url", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        atomic_session: 1,
        command: "list_all",
        fp: $fp
      })
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            data: res
          },
          () => console.log(this.state.data))
          ;
        }
      )

  }  

  render () {
  return (

    <DataSourcesWrapper>
      <AddDataSourcesButton>
        Add Data Source
      </AddDataSourcesButton> 
      <CardContainer>
      {this.state.data.map((card) => (
          <DataSourcesCard key={card.id}>
            <Logo src={IconWindowCogs} alt="Logo" />
            <EditButton>Edit</EditButton> <br />
            <DeleteButton>Delete</DeleteButton> <br />
            <TextHeader>{card.json.datasourceType}</TextHeader>
            <UList>
              <List>Command: <Span>{card.json.command}</Span></List>
              <List>Datasource Type: <Span>{card.json.datasourceType}</Span></List>
              <List>Host: <Span>{card.json.host}</Span></List>
              <List>ID: <Span>{card.json.id}</Span></List>
              <List>Password: <Span>{card.json.password}</Span></List>
              <List>Port: <Span>{card.json.port}</Span></List>
              <List>SQLDatabase: <Span>{card.json.sqlDatabaseType}</Span></List>
              <List>User: <Span>{card.json.user}</Span></List>

            </UList>

          </DataSourcesCard>
      ))}
      </CardContainer>
    </DataSourcesWrapper>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState()` is asynchronous and therefore you can't access the data as you did with the `console.log()` (synchronous).

To fix this, you can use the setState callback function that will be executed after the state value has updated:

```js
this.setState({ data: response }, () => console.log(this.state.data));
```

or use the `console.log(this.state.data)` in the `render` block.